# Order facet_wrap plots by descending order

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, facet-wrap

I am trying to plot with `facet_wrap` that by default is ordering the plots alphabetically. However, the desired result would be to order it by a numerically descending column.

Below is what I get:

```r
library(tidyverse)

M <- data.frame(
    A = LETTERS[1:10],
    B = round(rnorm(10,200,50)), 
    C = letters[15:24]
  )

ggplot(M, aes(A, B)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    facet_wrap(~C)
```

Instead, I am looking to get the plots ordered by column B descending

```r
arrange(M, desc(B)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(A, B)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    facet_wrap(~C)   ## need it ordered by B
```

I know one approach is to change the levels but I don´t know where in the sequence I can make it and how.

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by "get the plots ordered by column B descending". The B column is being used as the x-axis and you are apparently trying to tell facet_wrap to order by `C`.

Comment: Furthermore you are committing the grave error of using `cbind` after `as.data.frame`. You should eliminate the person or book that taught you that abomination from your list of credible sources of R programming.

Comment: hi, got the idea. I used cbind just to make the example. I thought it wouldn't be so bad. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: It's a horrible idea. `cbind` coerced that dataframe to a matrix x and therefore coerced your numeric values to character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reorder the factor levels of `C` according to the values of `B` (in descending order) using `forcats::fct_reorder` or base `reorder` inside the `facet_wrap`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

## data
M <- data.frame(
    A = LETTERS[1:10],
    B = round(rnorm(10,200,50)), 
    C = letters[15:24]
  )

## using fct_reorder
ggplot(M, aes(x = A, y = B)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    facet_wrap(facets = ~fct_reorder(C, B, .desc = TRUE))

## using base reorder
ggplot(M, aes(x = A, y = B)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    facet_wrap(facets = ~reorder(C, -B))   ## -B to get descending order
```

[image]

Comment: thank you Joris. Used base reorder and got it right.